# Contents List in Apple iWork Pages: how to get chapter numbering displayed?

Tags: macos, table-of-contents, iwork-pages

I'm making a report of approx. 100 pages. 6 Chapters, tiered numbering, so:

```
2. Chapter name
2.1 Introduction
2.2 ....
2.2.1
2.2.2
```

etc.

```
3. Chapter name
3.1 Introduction
```

etc.

Now I want to make a List of Contents. All the Chapter names appear, but no numbering.

I need not only a list of the Chapter and sub-chapter names and the page links. I want to see the numbering 2.1, 2.2 etc. etc. in that list too!

How can I achieve this?